# Laravel whereDate() with local timezone

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So, basically, I want to build this SQL; notice the **"localtime"**:

```
select [columns redacted] from "data"
where
  strftime('%Y-%m-%d', "time", "localtime") = cast("2019-05-27" as text)
```

So far, I've tried:

```
$data = data::select([columns redacted])
    ->whereDate('time', $date)
    ->get();
```

And, of course, it generates this:

```
select [columns redacted] from "data" where strftime('%Y-%m-%d', "time") = cast("2019-05-27" as text)
```

And I don't know how to pass the "localtime" to `whereDate()`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whereRaw

```
->whereRaw('strftime("%Y-%m-%d", time, "localtime") = ?', ['2019-05-27'])
```